# Problems migrating from IReport 3.0 to Jaspersotf studio 6.18.1

Tags: jasper-reports

I am executing a report created in IReport 3.0 in Jaspersoft Studio 6.18.1, I have made several migrations, but this has been a bit complicated for me, when executing it in IReport 3.0 it works correctly, in Jaspersoft Studio it does not, however there are times that the reports appear to me and when I replicate the changes it does not take effect either, for example: (the following instruction is in the where of the query)

```
TRIM(IIM.IFII) LIKE CASE WHEN '$P!{SIZE}' = ' ' THEN '%' ELSE '$P!{SIZE}' END
```

Changing $P!{SIZE} to just ' ' sometimes shows me the query, but then I try again and it doesn't show it anymore.
It is not a sql problem, it also does not show errors, only the empty document, if someone knows the reason for this, I appreciate your response in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.18.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.18.1-9d75d1969e774d4f179fb3be8401e98a0e6d1611  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Re040FE" pageWidth="955" pageHeight="612" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="NoPages" columnWidth="895" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="30" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="284b012e-355b-4301-ad46-3ed5c6840aea">
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <parameter name="AMB" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="BOD" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="INS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="NOM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="TAM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="CODI" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="CODF" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="LOC" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="LOT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="FLIB" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="VENCE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="EST" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="SINFV" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT IWM.WMFAC,
       ILI.LPROD,
       TRIM(IIM.IDESC) || ' ' || IIM.IDSCE AS DESC_PRD,
       IIM.IUMS,
       ILI.LWHS,
       ILI.LLOC,
       ILI.LLOT,
       CASE WHEN (ILI.LWHS LIKE 'N%' OR ILI.LWHS LIKE 'M%') AND (ILI.LWHS NOT IN ('M51', 'M04')) THEN ILN.LMRB ELSE ILI.LISTAT END AS LISTAT,
       ILI.LOPB + ILI.LRCT + ILI.LADJU - ILI.LISSU AS INV, 
       (ILI.LIALOC - COALESCE(ELA.CANT_ASIG,0)) AS INVT, 
       ILI.LOPB + ILI.LRCT + ILI.LADJU - ILI.LISSU - ILI.LIALOC AS INVD,
       IIM.IFII,
       IWM.LDESC,
       ZMF.MFDESC,
       ILN.LEXDT AS VEN,
       ILN.LQAAP AS CAL,
       TRIM(ILN.LNMLOT) AS LMAN,
       CASE WHEN ILI.LIWOPB + ILI.LIWRPT + ILI.LIWADJ - ILI.LIWISS < 0 THEN 0 ELSE ILI.LIWOPB + ILI.LIWRPT + ILI.LIWADJ - ILI.LIWISS END AS PESO,
       (ILI.LIALOC - COALESCE(ELA.CANT_TRANS,0)) AS INVA,
       (ILI.LOPB + ILI.LRCT + ILI.LADJU - ILI.LISSU - (ILI.LIALOC - COALESCE(ELA.CANT_ASIG,0))) AS INVTC
FROM $P!{AMB}.ILI AS ILI
   JOIN $P!{AMB}.IIM AS IIM ON ILI.LPROD = IIM.IPROD
   JOIN $P!{AMB}.IWM AS IWM ON ILI.LWHS = IWM.LWHS
   JOIN $P!{AMB}.ZMF AS ZMF ON IWM.WMFAC = ZMF.MFFACL
   LEFT OUTER JOIN $P!{AMB}.ILN AS ILN ON ILI.LPROD = ILN.LPROD 
                                      AND ILI.LLOT = ILN.LLOT
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ELA.APROD,
                            ELA.ALOT,
                            ELA.AWHS,
                            ELA.ALOC,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN ELA.ATYPE = 'S' THEN ELA.LQALL
                                     WHEN  ECH.CHSTS1 || ECH.CHSTS2 || ECH.CHSTS3 || ECH.CHSTS4 || ECH.CHSTS5 = '10000' THEN ELA.LQALL
                                     ELSE 0 END) AS CANT_ASIG,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN ELA.ATYPE = 'S' THEN 0
                                     WHEN  ECH.CHSTS1 || ECH.CHSTS2 || ECH.CHSTS3 || ECH.CHSTS4 || ECH.CHSTS5 <> '10000' THEN ELA.LQALL
                                  ELSE 0 END) AS CANT_TRANS
                     FROM $P!{AMB}.ELA ELA
                      JOIN $P!{AMB}.ECH ECH ON ELA.AORD = ECH.HORD
                     WHERE ELA.AWHS LIKE UCASE('$P!{BOD}%')
                     GROUP BY ELA.APROD,
                              ELA.ALOT,
                              ELA.AWHS,
                              ELA.ALOC) AS ELA ON ELA.APROD = ILI.LPROD AND ELA.ALOT = ILI.LLOT AND ELA.AWHS = ILI.LWHS AND ILI.LLOC = ELA.ALOC
WHERE (ILI.LOPB + ILI.LRCT + ILI.LADJU - ILI.LISSU <> 0)
   AND ILI.LWHS LIKE ucase('$P!{BOD}%')
   AND TRIM(IIM.IFII) LIKE  CASE WHEN '$P!{TAM}' = '' THEN '%' ELSE '$P!{TAM}' END 
   AND IIM.IDESC LIKE ucase('%$P!{NOM}%')
   AND  ILI.LPROD >= '$P!{CODI}' 
   AND ILI.LPROD <= CASE WHEN '$P!{CODF}' = '' THEN '999999999999999999' ELSE '$P!{CODF}' END 
   AND ILI.LLOC LIKE UCASE('$P!{LOC}%') AND (ILI.LLOT LIKE UCASE('$P!{LOT}%') )
   AND (iln.LQAAP is null OR (
                              (iln.LQAAP >= CASE WHEN '$P!{FLIB}' = '' THEN 0 ELSE '$P!{FLIB}' END)
                              AND
                              (iln.LEXDT <= CASE WHEN '$P!{VENCE}' = '' THEN 99999999 ELSE '$P!{VENCE}' END)   
                             )
       ) 
   AND (
        '$P!{EST}' = '' 
        OR
        iln.LMRB = '$P!{EST}'
       )
    AND (
        '$P!{SINFV}' = '' 
        OR
        '$P!{SINFV}' = 'N' 
        OR
        iln.LEXDT = CASE WHEN '$P!{SINFV}' = 'S' THEN '99999999' ELSE '0' END
       )
ORDER BY IWM.WMFAC,
         ILI.LWHS,
         IIM.IFII,
         ILI.LPROD,
         TRIM(iln.LNMLOT),
         ILI.LISTAT]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="WMFAC" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LPROD" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="DESC_PRD" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="IUMS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LWHS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LLOC" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LLOT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LISTAT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="INV" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="IFII" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LDESC" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="MFDESC" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="VEN" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="CAL" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="LMAN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PESO" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="INVT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="INVD" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="INVA" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="INVTC" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <variable name="TOT_COD" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="COD" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{INV}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="TOT_TAM" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="TAM" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{INV}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="TOT_BOD" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="BOD" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{INV}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="TOT_COD_PESO" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="COD" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{PESO}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="TOT_TAMT" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="TAM" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVT}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="TOT_TAMD" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="TAM" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVD}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="TOT_CODT" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="COD" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVT}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="TOT_CODD" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="COD" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVD}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="TOT_COD_A" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="COD" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVA}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="TOT_COD_TC" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="COD" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVTC}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="TOT_TAM_A" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="TAM" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVA}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="TOT_TAM_TC" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="TAM" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVTC}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="INS" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{WMFAC}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="26" splitType="Stretch">
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement key="rectangle-1" x="1" y="2" width="893" height="18" forecolor="#999999" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="5971d597-ff09-4849-9664-bbe9eb9ba5ec"/>
                </rectangle>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement key="textField" x="8" y="3" width="25" height="16" uuid="e92f1ccd-225a-40d1-b553-e6d0e5c6f0a1"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{WMFAC}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement key="textField-5" x="36" y="3" width="259" height="16" uuid="cc567073-a2cc-4852-a887-02abf5b04b87"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MFDESC}.toUpperCase()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="18" splitType="Stretch"/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    
    <group name="TAM" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{IFII}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="14" splitType="Stretch">
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement key="rectangle-2" x="1" y="0" width="546" height="12" forecolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="a602dfdc-12a8-463d-9879-80d4dd77f34f">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(!$F{IFII}.trim().equals("") )]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                </rectangle>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement key="textField" x="25" y="0" width="215" height="13" uuid="306d661f-055a-436d-ba14-aa832511417c"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="8" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{IFII}.trim().equals("") ? "" : "TAMAÑO " + $F{IFII}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement key="rectangle-3" x="166" y="3" width="381" height="12" forecolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="91467346-c518-418a-9649-c28f5ca89dd1">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(!$F{IFII}.trim().equals("") )]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                </rectangle>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement key="textField-6" x="167" y="3" width="100" height="13" uuid="84a7caa3-fa24-4156-993e-db5b5d5633fc"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="8" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{IFII}.trim().equals("") ? "" : "TOTAL TAMAÑO " + $F{IFII}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="#,##0.000" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement key="textField-7" x="594" y="2" width="57" height="13" uuid="eb4884cb-5f5d-4410-b8f8-cb1ce18a440d">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(!$F{IFII}.trim().equals("") )]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="8" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOT_TAMD}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement key="textField-9" x="660" y="2" width="42" height="13" uuid="5649bf74-9344-40b8-a3d5-33108c0e5e6a">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(!$F{IFII}.trim().equals("") )]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                        <font size="8" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{IUMS}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="#,##0.000" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement key="textField-27" x="533" y="2" width="57" height="13" uuid="48103168-496e-4701-8a26-1d8f08487532">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(!$F{IFII}.trim().equals("") )]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="8" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOT_TAMT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="#,##0.000" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement key="textField-28" x="350" y="2" width="57" height="13" uuid="ed4ec826-e26d-4e3d-b61d-89579b1c1ce8">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(!$F{IFII}.trim().equals("") )]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="8" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOT_TAM}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="#,##0.000" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement key="textField-32" x="411" y="2" width="57" height="13" uuid="efa54091-21ff-4260-880d-44ed6df999fe">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(!$F{IFII}.trim().equals("") )]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="8" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOT_TAM}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="#,##0.000" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement key="textField-33" x="472" y="2" width="57" height="13" uuid="ed5c9563-e1f0-4030-a302-f28707c77396">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(!$F{IFII}.trim().equals("") )]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="8" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOT_TAM_TC}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="34" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-1" x="1" y="0" width="893" height="19" uuid="4cf54817-5094-44aa-95af-0887883abc4e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[REPORTE DE INVENTARIO]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="1" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="13" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField" x="76" y="0" width="68" height="13" uuid="f77eb419-da24-4f68-981a-395d649d0f17"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LLOC}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField" x="135" y="0" width="214" height="13" uuid="79a474ea-f73a-4066-b20e-4e4f1920f441"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LLOT}.trim() +  (  $F{LMAN} == null ? "" :     ( $F{LMAN}.equals("") ? "" : "  /  " + $F{LMAN}     )

)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField" x="274" y="0" width="28" height="13" uuid="d02bae3e-0197-4487-9bc3-fbae2983369d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LISTAT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.000" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField" x="350" y="0" width="57" height="13" uuid="8f8326d8-a6b4-4fbe-a67a-9b43fbbe3794"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{INV}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField" x="659" y="0" width="43" height="13" uuid="7bb47536-b6aa-4c01-a06d-9b82303104f2"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{IUMS}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-1" x="42" y="0" width="34" height="13" uuid="ecaa6379-ca75-4124-b81b-e56f6380644f"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LWHS}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-10" x="839" y="0" width="56" height="13" uuid="776d859a-7d64-4e4b-a52c-ee3782424991"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{VEN}.toString().equals("0") || $F{VEN}.toString().equals("99999999") ? "" : $F{VEN}.toString().substring(0, 4).concat("/").concat($F{VEN}.toString().substring(4, 6).concat("/").concat($F{VEN}.toString().substring(6, 8)))]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-14" x="780" y="0" width="56" height="13" uuid="8abe232b-07f3-4fd8-bdd7-b8f2d952e6c5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CAL}.toString().equals("0") || $F{CAL}.toString().equals("99999999") ? "" : $F{CAL}.toString().substring(0, 4).concat("/").concat($F{CAL}.toString().substring(4, 6).concat("/").concat($F{CAL}.toString().substring(6, 8)))]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.0000" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField" x="706" y="0" width="52" height="13" uuid="c081d6e3-af0b-4501-9218-31b2afef6431">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{PESO}.doubleValue() > 0)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PESO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-16" x="759" y="0" width="17" height="13" uuid="228f63df-4ce3-4977-a3ae-d71a2c86f424">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{PESO}.doubleValue() > 0)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font size="8" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["KG"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.000" isBlankWhenNull="false" hyperlinkType="Reference" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement key="textField-21" x="533" y="0" width="57" height="13" uuid="ed560b89-febc-4bdb-abf7-244231940fb8"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA["DETALLE"]]></anchorNameExpression>
                <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["http://miportal:9010/MiPortal/pop.faces?AMB=" + $P{AMB}.trim() + "&PRODUCTO=" + $F{LPROD}.trim()  + "&BODEGA=" + $F{LWHS}.trim()  + "&UBICACION=" + $F{LLOC}.trim()+ "&OBJETO=RE040D"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.000" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-24" x="594" y="0" width="57" height="13" uuid="7905fa9e-94a4-40e6-b0e7-7a9b911c4b9f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVD}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.000" isBlankWhenNull="false" hyperlinkType="Reference" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement key="textField-30" x="411" y="0" width="57" height="13" uuid="b97d521a-e210-4f00-97c9-27c101fc9e70"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVA}]]></textFieldExpression>
                <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA["Detalle"]]></anchorNameExpression>
                <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["http://miportal:9010/MiPortal/pop.faces?AMB=" + $P{AMB}.trim() + "&PRODUCTO=" + $F{LPROD}.trim()  + "&BODEGA=" + $F{LWHS}.trim()  + "&UBICACION=" + $F{LLOC}.trim()+ "&OBJETO=RE040D"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.000" isBlankWhenNull="false" hyperlinkType="Reference">
                <reportElement key="textField-34" x="472" y="0" width="57" height="13" uuid="e12bbab2-26f8-4ade-be10-dc476789c9d6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{INVTC}]]></textFieldExpression>
                <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA["Detalle"]]></anchorNameExpression>
                <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["http://miportal:9010/MiPortal/pop.faces?AMB=" + $P{AMB}.trim() + "&PRODUCTO=" + $F{LPROD}.trim()  + "&BODEGA=" + $F{LWHS}.trim()  + "&UBICACION=" + $F{LLOC}.trim()+ "&OBJETO=RE040D"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the IReport version when doing the CASE WHEN... it could be placed directly:

```
ILI.LPROD <= CASE WHEN '$P!{CODF}' = '' 
                      THEN '999999999999999999' 
                      ELSE '$P!{CODF}' END
```

In the Jaspersotf studio 6.18.1 version when comparing with the ' ', the value it returns is not empty, but null, that's why when launching the query it returned the blank document, instead of placing the ' ' when comparing must be placed:

```
ILI.LPROD <= CASE WHEN '$P!{CODF}' = 'null' 
                      THEN '9999999999999' 
                      ELSE '$P!{CODF}' END
```

That solved the problem for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).